# Unity3d: Position a gameobject such that its forms a right angled triangle with other two gameobjects

Tags: unity, mathematics, transformation, angles, direction

[image]

How do I position `C gameObject` such that it forms a right angled triangle with `A and B`. I tried to use `(B.transform.position.x,A.transform.position.z)` but it still gives me something which is close to `A` (it takes it globally). I want the `C` to be along the `local red axis of A` and `local green axis of B` as seen in the picture. What do I do?

Comment: The problem as you've described it is over-constrained. Of the three criteria {on the local red axis through A, on the local green axis through B, forming a right-angled triangle with A and B}, two suffice to uniquely specify the point, and all three together can result in no solution if the orientation of A & B do not match. Would picking just two of these criteria suffice for your needs?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, yeah never thought about it! Picking just two criteria would be good!

Comment: @DMGregory But which two would be good so that I can get close to that point if not exact?

Comment: I would ignore B's rotation entirely.

Comment: @Draco18s How can I find the point perpendicular to B then?

Comment: The angle at C is required to be a right angle. The angle at A is fixed. A little SOHCAHTOA will get you the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking these two constraints:

- "position C gameObject such that it forms a right angled triangle with A and B"
- "I want the C to be along the local red axis of A"

We can solve this relatively easily using A's transformation:

```
// Transform point B into A's local space.
Vector3 bInAsSpace = a.transform.InverseTransformPoint(b.transform.position);

// Find a position along A's x-axis (y = z = 0 in A's local coordinates)
// that matches B's x-coordinate when viewed from A's frame of reference.
Vector3 cInAsSpace = new Vector3(bInAsSpace.x, 0, 0);

// Transform this position from A's local space back to world space.
Vector3 cInWordSpace = a.transform.TransformPoint(cInAsSpace);
```

This is guaranteed to be along A's x-axis (the red axis), since its y & z position in A's local space are both zero.

It's guaranteed to form a right-angled triangle with A & B because it forms a right triangle in A's local space (its separation from A is purely along the x-axis, and its separation from B has an x component of zero), and Unity transforms don't include shear.